# Error when trying to use glDrawArrays in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

I am trying to draw a simple rectangle in my game but I keep running into the following break:
[image]

Here is the code in my Sprite.cpp where I bind and render things.

```
void Sprite::init(float x, float y, float width, float height){

this->x = x;
this->y = y;
this->width = width;
this->height = height;


if(vbo == 0)
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

Vertex vertex[6];

vertex[0].setPosition(x, y);
vertex[0].setUV(0, 0);

vertex[1].setPosition(x, y + height);
vertex[1].setUV(0, 1);

vertex[2].setPosition(x + width, y + height);
vertex[2].setUV(1, 1);


vertex[3].setPosition(x, y);
vertex[3].setUV(0, 0);

vertex[4].setPosition(x + width, y);
vertex[4].setUV(1, 0);

vertex[5].setPosition(x + width, y + height);
vertex[5].setUV(1, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    vertex[i].setColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(vbo, sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}



void Sprite::render(){

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, uv));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}
```

If i comment out the line "glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)" Then the program will run perfectly fine. Here is my Vertex struct just for additional information:

```
#pragma once
#include <GL\glew.h>



struct Position {

float x, y;

};


struct UV{

float u, v;

};

struct Color {

GLubyte r, g, b, a;
};



struct Vertex {


Position position;

Color color;

UV uv;


void setUV(float u, float v) {
    uv.u = u;
    uv.v = v;
}

void setColor(GLubyte r, GLubyte g, GLubyte b, GLubyte a) {
    color.r = r;
    color.g = g;
    color.b = b;
    color.a = a;
}

void setPosition(float x, float y) {
    position.x = x;
    position.y = y;
}
};
```

I just seriously have no idea why this is happening. I have heard this error has to do with de-referencing some null pointer or something. I just don't know how to tackle this problem. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this: `glBufferData(vbo, sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);`

should be :`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

because the first argument specifies the how your array should be used.

Comment: I hate myself right now... Thank you so so much. I guess since I have been working on this for so long today it just needed a fresh pair of eyes. Thank you!

Comment: Lol ikr, we all did and still do the same mistake at some point! Cheers.